# How to prevent this loop breaking?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

In one of my test functions I have the following piece of code:

```
for key, expected_value in tools.config['expected_values']['devices']['specs'][device_spec].items():
    if expected_value > 0:
        try:
            value = data[device_spec][key]
            assert expected_value == value, pytest.fail('ERROR: Missing device using {}: {}.\nDetected: {}. Expected: {}\nEndpoint: {}'.format(device_spec, key, value, expected_value, endpoint), pytrace=False)
        except KeyError:
            pytest.fail('ERROR: There are no clients using {}: {}\nExpected: {}\nEndpoint: {}'.format(device_spec, key, expected_value, endpoint), pytrace=False)
            raise SystemExit(1)
```

It might fail for two different reasons:

1. Because there are not the expected number of devices using some expected specifications (e.g. 4 Linux are detected but 7 were expected).
2. Because there are not devices at all using certain spec (e.g. there is no Windows device).

The thing is that during the test runtime, both conditions might meet. For example, the config might be:

```
expected_values:
  devices:
    specs:
      operating_systems:
        LINUX: 1
        MACOS: 2
        WINDOWS: 0
        ANDROID: 1
        IOS: 1
```

And assume there is only 1 MacOS device and there are not Android devices. The output should be:

```
ERROR: Missing device using operating_system: MACOS.
Detected: 1. Expected: 2
Endpoint: example.com/api/operating_system

ERROR: There are no clients using operating_system: Android. 
Expected: 1. 
Endpoint: example.com/api/operating_system
```

In fact, if I add a `print(key)`, I can confirm that LINUX is displayed, MACOS is displayed, and after that, the code stops. It didn't read the other keys.

However, only the first one is displayed and my guess is that the `pytest.fail` is breaking the `for`. So, how can I prevent this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found why it's not working as expected. The problem is the `pytest.fail` I was suspecting. When `pytest.fail` is called, it fails the whole test, so no code is executed after it.

So, it's not that `pytest.fail` is breaking the `for` loop, it's that `pytest.fail` is breaking the whole test function. So I will need to refactor that code by not using `pytest.fail` at that point.

Answer (score 1):

```
  except KeyError:
            pytest.fail('ERROR: There are no clients using {}: {}\nExpected: {}\nEndpoint: {}'.format(device_spec, key, expected_value, endpoint), pytrace=False)
            raise SystemExit(1)
```

SystemExit(1) is the main reason of loop break, which is causing the  force termination of program. simply by removing it from code will work fine.

Comment: that would make sense if the code would have entered the KeyError except first. But check the updated expected output (basically the same, just the other way around), first the code fails at the assert, and then it's just breaking the loop.

Comment: raise SystemExit(1) was  not either correct in your code it will also break your for loop.